# Can JSF instantiate immutable objects?

Tags: jsf, immutability, jsf-2.2

I have a project with VRaptor, a MVC framework. And my DTOs are immutable like this:

```
 public class City {
        private final Long id;
        private final String name;

        public City(Long id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        // getters
    }
```

Now I'm migrate this app to use JSF. But as I read, JSF needs getters and setters for all properties.

There are way to change this behaviour creating a converters or another approaching?

Comment: How will a typical usage look like? B/c the missing default constructor will be a concern if the framework tries to proxy the DTO.

Comment: @mabi, it's only a design decision. I use DTOs only to get inputed data from the page. So there is no reason to use mutable objects. In my example, using City DTO class, the city never changes, so there is no setters. One time City was created, will never changed. Frameworks like vraptor can instantiate only using constructor. So my goal is to use the same behaviour in JSF.

Comment: Thing is, JSF (or rather, EL) utilizes reflection on your class to set its values. It needs a no-arg constructor to do that. Conceptually, JSF is stateful,  modelling your user working on the exposed JSF object. So while it's possible to have such a DTO in your backend system (but Adam Bien [points out](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/javaee_7_retired_the_dto) you don't have to), using this in the frontend doesn't fit JSF's design. Of course, "backend" implies constructing this yourself (eg, from an action method that collects fields off of a `@ManagedBean`).

Comment: I like your comment, @mabi. What do you think to move as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't write to those properties via input there won't be any problems.
The only scenario I can think of, where this is true, is a `@ManagedProperty`. For those you will need setter and getter methods, but that will apply on Managed Beans, not on your TOs.

Comment: I really sorry for my long delay to answer you. My goal is JSF instantiate the object by me without using setters, only the constructor, that means, JSF needs to write all fields inputed by users using only constructors. Thank you.